# CefSharp - Is it possible to save IFrame.ViewSource() into specific file name?

Tags: c#, .net, cefsharp

I'm having problems with trying to save HTML source code into specific file. My goal is to save data that I get from "chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.ViewSource();" in "OnLoadingStateChanged" method into a file named "html.txt". Is it possible to do that?

```
        public void InitializeChromiumWebBrowser()
        {
            CefSettings cefSettings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(cefSettings);
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com");
            this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            chromeBrowser.LoadingStateChanged += OnLoadingStateChanged;
        }

        private void OnLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (!args.IsLoading)
                    chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.ViewSource();
        }
```

I need exactly this method that is used in given code.
I've tried getting HTML Code through WebClient, HTTPWebRequest, GetSourceAsync, but none of those solutions work for my case.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Using GetSourceAsync is the simplest option,  usually wait a few hundred milliseconds after page has loaded before calling.